# insert overwrite from spark is changing permission and owner of the hive table directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a simple requirement to read a hive parquet table and overwrite into the same table after applying logic.

**beeline::**

```
create external table test_table (id int,name string) stored as parquet location '/dev/test_db/test_table';
insert into test_scd values (1,'John'),(2,'Myna'),(3,'Rakesh');
```

**pyspark**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
src_table=spark.sql("select * from test_db.test_table")

src_table.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("test_db.temp_test_table")
tempDF=spark.sql("select * from test_db.temp_test_table")
spark.sql("insert overwrite table test_db.test_table select * from test_db.temp_test_table")
```

**result::**

It overwrites the table as expected. But it changes the permission of the table directory.
In this case it changes the permission of '/dev/test_db/test_table' from **771 to 755**. Also it changes the owner of the group from **hive:hive** to **batch_user:hive**.

Since it changes the permission from the group level, I cannot write into this table from hive2 server , may it beeline or hue or any third party tool such as Oracle ODI.

Has anyone faced such issue. I am surprised why spark job is changing the directory permission. In most of the operations it doesn't change the permission, keep it as **hive:hive**. But in case of overwrite it is doing as per my analysis.
I have tried other apis like **"saveAsTable"** and **"insertInto"**. In both cases it does the same.

Comment: If anyone can try the code and share the results, it would be great. Its bit urgent, if anyone can help.

Comment: Are you using Sentry? If Yes, Have you set the correct ACL's for the HDFS directory where the data is being written? Or do you have HDFS Sentry Sync enabled?

Comment: We use Sentry in our CDH cluster. I can check with admin on if the HDFS Sync enabled or not. But can you try and confirm me if this issue doesn't exist for you.

Actually when the table gets created, it has the access of 771, only when I do insert overwrite I am seeing it is changing the permission to 755. Other operations like inserting or appending is working fine without any issue with hive:hive ownership.